# Как проверить валидность кода CSS введённого в форму через JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, валидация

В форму вводится текст `CSS`, надо на стороне браузера проверить его валидность, либо выкинуть всё что не валидно и оставить только валидную часть. Как это можно сделать?

```css
#textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea">.selector1 {
   color: red;
}
.selector2 div {
   font-weight: bold;
}
some_strange_code #^</textarea>
<button onclick="test()">Проверить</button>
```

Лучше решение для меня будет без использования сторонних библиотек, но решение со сторонними библиотеками тоже подходит, предпочтение отдаётся легковесности библиотеки, желательно даже одна функция которую можно скопировать к себе.

Возможно какое-то браузерное решение где введённый `css` подключается внутрь страницы, вероятно браузер поправит этот `css`, а всё что не понял - выкинет.   Такое решение меня тоже устроит, главное что бы на выходе был нормальный валидный `css`.
Добавить введённый `css` на страницу не проблема, но вот извлечь пока не понимаю как.
Если добавлять внутрь тега `style` то извлечёт в том же виде что и добавляешь без исправлений. Видимо надо извлекать как-то иначе, не через dom.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21223418/4928642

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Если надо очистить код до того, что понимает текущий браузер

Обращаю внимание, что хотя блоки `@supports` остаются, если текущий браузер не поддерживает соответствующие стили, такие свойства будут удалены из правил. То же касается вендорных префиксов.

В сниппете не работает из-за настроек безопасности на SO, но на jsfiddle всё хорошо: https://jsfiddle.net/usjqmhf8/2/

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  var css = document.querySelector('textarea').value

  var doc = document.querySelector('iframe').contentDocument
  doc.open()
  doc.write(`<!DOCTYPE html><title>CSS</title><style></style>`)
  doc.close()
  doc.querySelector('style').textContent = css
  
  var res = [...doc.styleSheets[0].cssRules].map(s => s.cssText).join("\n")
  document.querySelector('pre').textContent = res;
})
```

```css
[hidden] { display: none !important; }
html, body, textarea, pre { height: 100%; margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
textarea, pre { width: 50%; float: left; overflow: auto; resize: none; }
button { position: absolute; top: 8px; right: 25px; }
```

```html
<textarea>.selector1 {
   text-overflow: -o-ellipsis-lastline;
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   -moz-appearance: none;
   appearance: none;
   color: red;
}
.selector2 div {
   font-weight: bold;
   rubbish
}
@supports (qqq: www) {
  @media only print {
    qwe:zxc {
      abc: xyz;
    }
    qwe:hover {
      qqq: www;
      color: silver
    }
  }
}
some_strange_code #^
</style><script>alert(1)</script>
{} a { color: red }</textarea>
<button>Проверить</button>
<iframe hidden sandbox="allow-same-origin"></iframe>
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: Очень круто!...

Comment: А что за [hidden] в css, не встречал раньше... Это что так можно стилизовать теги с конкретным аттрибутом?

Comment: Свойство `hidden` по стандарту отвечает за скрытие элемента. Браузером оно синхронизируется с атрибутом. Но в браузерных стилях для него просто `display: none`, что перебивается любым другим значением в селекторе по классу, поэтому рекомендуется в собственном стиле прописывать его же с `!important` (в браузерном этого делать не стали вроде бы из-за совместимости).

Comment: Понял. А что за квадратные скобки в css?

Comment: @ДимитрийПолянин, https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B

Answer (score 1):

Использую вот эту [либу](https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-validator), пакетов подтягивает не много, мало весит, шустрая, можно юзать

Comment: Подозрительно выглядит: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWcEa.png. Но вроде как-то работает.

Comment: А она чисто вилидирует, то есть выдаёт всё хорошо или плохо, или может так же обрезать инвалидные куски?